# Neo4j: Combination of math calculation and Match query returns null value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I want to combine my query and get **collection** from my "**Match Query**" and calculate some computations -> neo4j returns **NULL**

While when I make separation it seems ok and I have proper result , I meant when I run:
1. getting collection -> it works
2. computation -> also works
but both of them can not work

```
    create 
    (_0  {`name`:"Mahsa"}),
    (_1  {`name`:"Frank"}),
    (_2  {`name`:"Tag1"}),
    (_3  {`name`:"Tag2"}),
    (_4  {`name`:"Tag3"}),
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 1}]->_2,
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 2}]->_3,
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 3}]->_4,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 4}]->_2,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 5}]->_3,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 6}]->_4


    MATCH (p1:Person {username: 'Mahsa' })-[x:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)<-[y:TAGGED]-(p2:Person {username: 'Frank'})
 WITH x.frequency AS aColl, y.frequency AS bColl
 UNWIND aColl AS a
 WITH collect(a) AS aColl, avg(a) AS aAvg, bColl
 UNWIND bColl AS b
 WITH aColl, aAvg, collect(b) AS bColl, avg(b) AS bAvg
 Return REDUCE(x = 0.0, i IN range(0, size(aColl)- 1)| x +((aColl[i]- aAvg)*(bColl[i]- bAvg)))/(size(aColl) - 1) as cov
```

@Nicole White: That is intersting and I got it why x.frequencytotal is not a collection and we should try on collect it.

**Before Making Collection:**
[image]

**After Making Collection:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong here. `x.frequency` and `y.frequency` are not collections; UNWINDing them has no effect. You created data without any labels and yet you are querying for labels so you won't get any results. Your property on the Person node is `name` and yet you are querying for `username`, again leading to no results.

I've changed the data you provided to what I think you want it to be.

```
create 
    (_0:Person  {`username`:"Mahsa"}),
    (_1:Person  {`username`:"Frank"}),
    (_2:Tag  {`name`:"Tag1"}),
    (_3:Tag  {`name`:"Tag2"}),
    (_4:Tag  {`name`:"Tag3"}),
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 1}]->_2,
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 2}]->_3,
    _0-[:TAGGED { frequency: 3}]->_4,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 4}]->_2,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 5}]->_3,
    _1-[:TAGGED { frequency: 6}]->_4
```

Then, the query to get covariance is:

```
MATCH (:Person {username:'Mahsa'})-[x:TAGGED]->(:Tag)<-[y:TAGGED]-(:Person {username:'Frank'})
WITH AVG(x.frequency) AS avg_x, 
     AVG(y.frequency) AS avg_y, 
     COLLECT(x.frequency) AS x_col, 
     COLLECT(y.frequency) AS y_col
RETURN REDUCE(s = 0.0, i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(x_col) - 1) | s + ((x_col[i] - avg_x) * (y_col[i] - avg_y))) / (SIZE(x_col) - 1) AS cov;
```

You can take a closer look here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/8vdp81

In this case the covariance is 1 since your observations are [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]:

```
> cov(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
[1] 1
```

Comment: thank you so much for your prompt answer, so this is why I got this error "Element access is only possible by performing a collection lookup using an integer index, or by performing a map lookup using a string key" when I used x.frequency and y.frequency as collection because they are not. and why they are not collection? I am not sure but I think they are somehow collection but without indexing. is not it? or am I wrong?